# Updating to built-in 'templatefile' in terraform from using 'template_file' in data block

Tags: terraform

Trying to change from using template_file in terraform to using the templatefile function.

The function takes in two arguments normally - 'the path-to-file' and 'the objects(key-value pair)'.

Please how can I do this for a code without a specific .tf, or .yml or .json or .sh file. with the code:

```
    data "template_file" "test1" {
      template = jsonencode(
        concat(
          [
            {
              "name": "MY_KEY",
              "valueFrom": "${local.ssm_path}/MY_KEY"
            }
          ]
        )
      )
    }
```

Normally it should be something like this:

```
    "new_para" : ${templatefile("/testfile.yml", {
          var1 = para1
          var2 = para2
    }
    )}
```

but not sure how to use the templatefile when there is no actual file available as in the code, just objects.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do doesn't entirely make sense, at least not the way you've described it. I don't think you need the template_file datasource for what you're trying to achieve. You don't look to be doing anything except basic variable interpolation, so it's likely all you actually need to do is this:

```
local {
  test1 = jsonencode({
    name      = "MY_KEY"
    valueFrom = "${local.ssm_path}/MY_KEY"
  })
}
```

And then reference `local.test1` where you'd have previously used `data.template_file.test1.rendered`. The full interpolation syntax available within the template_file datasource is also available within Terraform itself as of 0.12, which is why template_file is redundant. You're not limited to simple string interpolation, but can also use the `%{...}` interpolation syntax for directives, such as in this (contrived) example:

```
local {
  test2 = <<EOT
%{~ for i in range(5) ~}
${i}
%{ endfor ~}
EOT
}
```

I think it might help to give a more detailed example including an example of the kind of output you expect.

Comment: Hi keith,
thank you. You are absolutely right. I used the 'locals' block and its just perfect.
Grateful.